# Como crear un elemento que contenga uno o mas elementos de distintas Tablas de mi base de datos Django

Tags: django, django-models, model-view-controller

Tengo las siguientes Tablas:   **Ticket**, **encargado** y **servicios**

**Ticket**  tiene infomacion como fecha de creacion, encargado , servicios y mas. **encargado** que tiene 2 campos nombre y porcentaje. y la tabla **servicios** que tiene 2 campos servicios y precio.

quiero crear una vista donde pueda introducir los datos del ticket y agregar uno o mas servicios  en el mismo ticket.

ya tengo el formulario tanto para introduccir reponsable y servicios,  tengo la vista que muestra los ticket que estan en la base de datos 
 lo que no tengo idea es como hacer que un ticket tenga uno o mas servicios  al momento de crear el ticket

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Servicios(models.Model):
    servicio = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    precio = models.FloatField()


class Encargado(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    porcentaje = models.FloatField()

class Ticket(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    servicio = models.ForeignKey(Servicios)
    encargado = models.ForeignKey(Encargado)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    p_unitario = models.FloatField()
    total = models.FloatField()


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Main:get-list')
```

Comment: ¿Cuándo dices _"bases de datos"_ quieres decir __"tablas"__? Aclara el asunto, porque si quieres usar dos o más bases de datos las respuestas te pueden llevar por otro camino. Tal vez te falte otra tabla, que recopile todos los servicios que forman un ticket.

Comment: @toledano en efecto,  son tablas  ahorita mismo hago la correcion. gracias

Comment: Mira esto: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ e intenta aplicarlo a tu caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dijo @toledano si quieres que un ticket tenga uno o mas de un servicio y que un servicio tenga multiples tickets puedes usar manytomany quedaria algo como:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    servicio = models.ManyToManyField(Servicios)
    encargado = models.ForeignKey(Encargado)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    p_unitario = models.FloatField()
    total = models.FloatField()
```

o puedes aplicar la llave foranea en el modelo `Servicios` y un ticket tendria varios servicios pero un servicio tendria solo un tiquete

Comment: Yo prefiero la segunda opción, pero con una tabla auxiliar que controle los servicios en cada ticket. De otro modo, tendría que ponerle siempre `precio` a todos los servicios.

Comment: @toledano los servicios siempre deben tener un precio a menos que permita null, como ves lo que agregas es un objeto, y esto siempre conlleva todas sus columnas, en cuanto a cual seria mejor, creo que me iria por la segunda opcion, pero depende de lo que quiero victor

Comment: Me refiero a que el servicio (con su precio) deben ir en otra tabla, en la tabla auxiliar solo referencias al ticket y al servicio. Desde el ticket se puede obtener acceso a todo a través de servicio_set y servicioporticket_set... algo asi.

Comment: @toledano No es necesario crear otra tabla, estarias perdiendo la normalizacion de los datos, es mejor mantenerlo simple. Pero obviamente, todo depende de las necesidades del usuario

Comment: Muchas gracias chicos! intentare la solucion que propone @Mauricio Cortazar.  Apenas estoy aprendiendo programacion en genral. y de antemano veo que tambien voy a tener dificultades al momento de crear la vista para la creacion de los tickets en especial la parte donde me permita meter los servicios que llevara ese ticket. alguno de ustedes podra apuntarme en la direccion correcta  un tutorial  o donde pueda encontrar informacion respecto a lo que quiero hacer?

Comment: Entiendo que con  DetailView puedo ver el detalle de cada ticket la pregunta es como agrego los servicios... si no me equivoco solo me dejaria meter un servicio de la lista pero como podria hacer para segir agregando servicios . nisiquiera se como le puedo llamar a eso o algun termino que me permita buscarlo en google .

Comment: @victorR Si te ayudo no te olvides darle upvote y aceptarlo, también respondí esta misma pregunta tuyo en inglés si quieres haces lo mismo. Si quieres me escribes al correo y podría ayudarte